# Eloquent Model is just displaying "value" and not inserting

Tags: php, eloquent

I have got the following Eloquent insert:

```php
/** @var WebsiteFileSearch $insert */
$insert = WebsiteFileSearch::query()->create([
    'value' => 'test',
    'path' => 'test',
    'line' => 12
]);
// $insert->website()->associate($this->website);
$result = $insert->save();

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
exit;
```

However the dump just displays `value` on my screen and no insert is done...

**WebsiteFileSearch**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class WebsiteFileSearch extends Model
{
    public function regex()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(WebsiteFileSearchRegex::class);
    }
    public function website()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Website::class);
    }
}
```

I have got `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` on my connection, but there are no errors. Any ideas what is going on here?

## Edit

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `website_file_searches` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `website_file_search_regex_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `website_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `value` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `path` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    `line` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

`create` tries to save the new model to the database, and this might be a problem, since it's missing the reference to the `Website` related model. So try to use `make` instead (which just makes a model, without persisting it), and the insert is done when you call `save`, after you have associated it properly.

```
$insert = WebsiteFileSearch::make([
    'value' => 'test',
    'path' => 'test',
    'line' => 12
]);
$insert->website()->associate($this->website);
$insert->save();
```

Or, you can try to use `create` directly:

```
$insert = WebsiteFileSearch::create([
    'value' => 'test',
    'path' => 'test',
    'line' => 12,
    'website_id' => $this->website->id // Or similar.
]);
```

Comment: Still does the same thing, I have commented out the `associate` for now. And just trying to create a model with them 3 attributes results in the same thing. There `value` dump is happening somewhere within `save`, as nothing below that line dumps out.

Comment: do both of my snippets fail to save the model to the database?

Comment: Yeah, using `insert` works fine however, so the connection and table is fine.

Comment: Doing some debugging within the vender files. It appears it's not getting past the `newQueryWithoutScopes` call within the `save` method...

Comment: can you show me the full model and table definition?

Comment: Updated my post with the full model and table create sql

Comment: Just had a thought, i'm using `"illuminate/database": "^5.4"`, but i'm running PHP `5.6.31`, not able to upgrade right now. I have a feeling that this might be an issue when using the `create` methods?

Comment: i am not sure, it's quite suspicious to me that both ways of inserting fail, but if there is no reason to use old versions, i suggest you upgrade them

Comment: what about `$this->website`, is it already persisted?

Comment: My mistake, we are running PHP 7+, so that's not the issue. `$this->website` is persisted, however even with commenting the `associate` out I still get the same issue.

Comment: what if you try `$insert = WebsiteFileSearch::make([..]);` and then  `$this->website->files()->save($insert);` Btw, did you define the inverse relation on the Website model?

Comment: I tried `make` and this also just displays `value` and doesn't save. Oh no I didn't make the inverse relation. But like I said even just doing a `create` and attempting to save that new model, without the `associate` has the same issue, so the `associate` isn't the issue here. I'm going to install `Xdebug` tomorrow and step through the code, I think this is the best bet, as it's exiting within the `save` method of `Eloquent`.

Comment: `make` never saves to the database, but i suggest you try to define the inverse relation and maybe the foreign key in the table definition

Comment: maybe try to declare the `$fillable` proprieties on the `WebsiteFileSearch` model, like: `public $fillable = [ 'website_file_search_regex_id', 'website_id', 'value' , 'path', 'line' ];`